# How to find the coordinates of a line in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, discrete-mathematics

I am developing a Building Plan Drawing Application in HTML5.
For that I needed to place the doors and windows on walls.
Usually, the walls (lines) are not straight.
How can I find if my mouse has touched the walls (lines) while moving the door Image.
Moreover, I should find the X, Y and angle of the door to be drawn.
Please help...

Comment: -1 add your code please

Comment: Save it in an array and compare the coordinates? What is so hard? =/

Comment: Save the whole points of the line in an array :-o I have only X1, Y1,X2, Y2 of the line.
And the doors will be smaller than the line. It can be placed anywhere in the line.

Comment: @Infer-On How can I add the code which I have not done :-o

Comment: @YesudassIbnJesus add your code please

Comment: @Infer-On: Be kind!  The questioner wants to know how to calculate the point on a line-segment that's closest to the mouse so he can decide if-and-where a door image should be placed on that line-segment.  He doesn't know how to begin so he doesn't have any *relevant* code to show us--he needs a starting place to begin coding.

Comment: @markE when I read, "building Plan drawing application", I thought He had already written something. I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's one way:**

Save all your line segments (walls) in an array.

```
var walls=[];

var wall={x0:50,y0:50,x1:150,y1:150};

walls.push(wall);
```

When you are dragging your window into place, compare the mouse position to the nearest point on every line segment (wall).  Place the window on whichever wall is closest to the mouse.

This function will give you the closest point to the mouse on any given line segment:

```
// given a line defined like this

var line={x0:50,y0:50,x1:150,y1:150};

// calculate the closest point on the line to [x,y]

function getClosestPointOnLine(line,x,y) {
    //
    lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };
    var dx=line.x1-line.x0;
    var dy=line.y1-line.y0;
    var t=((x-line.x0)*dx+(y-line.y0)*dy)/(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    t=Math.min(1,Math.max(0,t));
    var lineX=lerp(line.x0, line.x1, t);
    var lineY=lerp(line.y0, line.y1, t);
    return({x:lineX,y:lineY});
};
```

And this function will return the distance between 2 points (those 2 points being the mouse position and the calculated point on a wall).

```
// get distance between 2 points

function distance(x0,y0,x1,y1){
    var dx=x1-x0;
    var dy=y1-y0;
    return(Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy));
}
```

Finally, google the built-in javascript `Math.atan2` to get the angle of your wall to use as the angle of your window.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Aha! How's lerping now?? :) I think perhaps f.ex. the `t` formula can be a bit hard to understand for a beginner (?) - I would suggest comment those to make it more clear what goes on there.

Comment: Hi @MarkE Thanks for your solution, I am trying it ... But, I didnt get what distance returns..  Is it a single number ? But, It should be xDistance and yDistance should be there naa ?

Comment: Wow,,, it works... Thanks so much mark..  I removed sqrt and used only dx and dy in distance function.. now I get the X, Y distance to the nearest point :) Thanks lot..