# How to force cursor move only on polyline?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I working on application and I have there a polyline draw on canvas layout from top to bottom without a regular order.
The mouse move over the canvas a cursor is showing up and I want to force him to move only according to the Y Coordinate of mouse position on the polyline.

So far i succeed to do it by finding how much pixels every centimeter is taking on the canvas (the polyline is a collection of ranges with independent spaces between them) but its not good enough.

Someone can think on another way?

Comment: Here is a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610167/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-a-line-in-html5-canvas/23611965#23611965) describing how to find the nearest point on a line given mouseX,mouseY.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at polyline.PointToScreen and PointFromScreen, this way you'll be able to have a Point p = mouse coords relative to polyline's (0, 0).

Then, you'll have to compute projection of p on each segment of the polyline.

tip : to compute P' = projection of P on segment S (P1,P2)

1. compute line L1 defined by P1, P2
2. compute line L2 which is the perpendicular to L1 which goes through P
3. compute intersection P' of L1 and L2
4. if P' is between P1 and P2 : stop
5. else, if not : if dist(P1P') < dist(P2P') : set P' = P1 and stop
6. else : set P' = P2  and stop

and while going through all polyline segments S, keep always the P' where dist(PP') is minimal.

finally : set mouse position to P'.

This way you'll always have your mouse placed exactly on the polyline.

- optional : if you only want Y of the mouse to follow polyline, set only mouse Y to P'.y

You can show your piece of code if still stuck, this way I could show you more precisely.

**Refined answer for searching only from horizontal line :**

1. get mouse xCoord
2. foreach segment of polyline
3. If mouse xCoord is between segment ends then compute intersection between segment and vertical line at xCoord

You can do the same for yCoord :
If polyline segments follow each other only on X-Axis search for intersection between segment and a vertical line(mouse xCoord)
If polyline segments follow each other on Y-Axis search for intersection between segment and an horizontal line(mouse yCoord)

Il polyline don't follow any rule, use first answer is best choice.

Comment: Thank you.This solution look bit heavy in run type for a given polyline with something like 200 segments now? Considering that mouse can move very quickly.... I will try it. Can you think on solution for search on current horizonal line of the canvas for where the mouse is at any moment and find the pixel that represent the polyline for this horizonal line?

Comment: @Nadavp. Divide your canvas into 4,8 or 16 orthants. Search the lines in and around the orthants closest to the mouse first.

Comment: I edited / completed my answer accordingly to the new question. 
Please feedback if this suits your problem.